# How to send all "Undeliverable Mail" notifications to a single email address with POSTFIX

Tags: postfix, email

When my site tries to send an email to a bad domain, my postfix server sends an "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender" notification to the sending account.

How can I instead send these notifications to a single email account, regardless of the sender?

If this is not possible, is there a way to disable these notifications?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [notify_classes](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#notify_classes) directive is probably what you're looking for.

```
notify_classes = resource, software, bounce
```

Comment: So if I use the above config and also set bounce_notice_recipient to admin@example.com, will the notifications go to just admin@example.com or will they also be sent to the Sender?

Comment: So I just tested this and the postmaster gets a copy of the headers of "Undelivered Mail..." message and the sender gets the entire thing. What I would like is for the postmaster to get the Undelivered message and for the sender to get nothing.

Comment: @VladimirGiverts did soft_bounce work for you?

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to disable the notifications by setting "soft_bounce = yes".

Comment: soft\_bounce will merely cause the message to stay in the queue until it times out.